# Error when introducing huge data in Neo4j from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am trying to introduce a huge amount of data in neo4j from a file. I am using node.js code, simple javascript with no much complexity.

The thing is that I have 386213 lines or 'nodes' to introduce, but when executed (and wait 3 hours) I only see the half moreless. I think some of the queries are lost in the way, but I do not know why...

I am using npm node-neo4j package for the connection and that.

Here my node.js code:

```
    var neo4j = require('neo4j');
    var readline = require("readline");
    var fs = require("fs")

    var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:Gemitis26@localhost:7474');

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/RRamos/Documents/Projects/test-neo4j/Files/kaggle_songs.txt')
    });

    var i=1;

    rl.on('line', function (line) {
        var str = line.split(" ");
        db.cypher({
            query: "CREATE (:Song {id: '{line1}', num_id: {line2}})",
            params: {
            line1: str[0],
            line2: str[1],
            },
        }, callback);
        console.log(i + " " + "CREATE (:Song {id: '"+str[0]+"', num_id: "+str[1]+"})");
        i = i+1;
    });


    function callback(err, results){
        if(err) throw err;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making 386213 separate Cypher REST queries (in separate transactions) is probably the slowest possible way to create such a large number of nodes.

There are at least 3 better ways (in order of increasing performance):

1. Create multiple nodes at a time by sending as a parameter an array  containing the data for multiple nodes. For example, you can create 8 nodes by sending this array parameter: `[['a', 1],['b', 2],['c', 3],['d', 4],['e', 5],['f', 6],['g', 7],['h', 8]]`, and using this query:

   ```
   UNWIND {data} AS d
   CREATE (:Song {id: d[0], num_id: d[0]})
   ```
2. You can use the [LOAD CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) clause to create the nodes. Since your input file seems to use a space to separate node property values, this *might* work for you:

   ```
   LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///C:/Users/RRamos/Documents/Projects/test-neo4j/Files/kaggle_songs.txt' AS line
   FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
   CREATE (:Song {id: line[0], num_id: line[1]})
   ```
3. For even better performance, you could use the [Import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html), which is a command line tool for initializing a new DB.

Comment: WOW! That 2nd way has KILLED me!!!! Thank you so much. I spent like 30 hours trying it, and ONLY executing that 3 lines it take 12 seconds !!!!!!

Comment: ABSOLUTELY AWESOME